# Blow dictionary out to a list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary with this signature:

```
Dictionary<decimal, int>
```

Items inside it look like this:

```
90, 2
60, 3
30, 4
20, 1
```

I need to blow this out to a list that has this signature:

```
List<double>
```

Items inside would look like this:

```
90
90
60
60
60
30
30
30
30
20
```

Any ideas on how to do this in an elegant and efficient way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

```
dictionary
  .SelectMany(pair => Enumerable.Repeat((double)pair.Key, pair.Value))
  .OrderByDescending(x => x)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OrderBy is part of the requirement.

Comment: @spender, OP didn't specify but put the elements in order so I errored on making sure mine matched the output.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that given that the order of enumeration of a Dictionary is not defined, OP will need to pay attention the either the ordering prior to SelectMany or after (as you have done).

Comment: I wish I could + more than 1.  Great answer

Answer (score 5):

```
dictionary
    .SelectMany(kvp => Enumerable.Repeat(Decimal.ToDouble(kvp.Key), kvp.Value))
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var pair in dict)
    for (int i=0;i<pair.Value;i++)
        list.Add((double)pair.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Blowout<T>(T value, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) yield return value;
}

dictionary
    .SelectMany(pair => Blowout((double)pair.Key, pair.Value));
```